# VS Dependency Validation Diagram: Super- and SubNamespaces

Tags: visual-studio

When I have a namespace included in my Layerdiagram (eg. Solution.Data), are the subnamespaces (e.g. Solution.Data.DB) also checked?

Visual Studio always tries to add each namespace as a different artifact in the diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, subnamespaces ARE covered when dependency diagram contains dependency rules between parent namespaces.

Tested with VS2019.